# Angular Universal not re-hydrating DOM nodes on client

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

As far as I have read and implemented, Angular Universal renders an HTML in the server but the DOM nodes are not reused in the client. I came across solutions where we can store HTTP responses to avoid HTTP requests at the client but it still renders the application completely again. Moreover, transferring API responses to the client in HTML seems to me like I'm passing the same data twice in the same HTML. (once in rendered content, once in TransferState). Is there a better way to achieve this? Perhaps a method to tell angular to reuse existing DOM rendered from the server? Or some way to tell Angular to not render a particular component in the client application

Comment: I'm afraid this is how it works. Smart hydration of the generated DOM is not supported in Angular (not in any framework as far as I'm aware). With regards to transferState - if correctly implemented it should only pass the state inside the generated HTML and not re-request the same data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe smart hydration is now present in React. And yes TransferState would avoid an HTTP request on the client.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is disclosed on github, in theory, the problem will be solved this year
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13446

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).